# In a beamer slide highlight a region of an image with a rectangle overlay

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics, overlays, rounded-corners

I have a slide with a figure in it.  I want to draw a rounded corner rectangle overtop part of a figure to highlight that section.  Bonus points if you can draw two  rounded rectangles as overlays that appear one at a time.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{ESR1} 

    \begin{center}
        Functional analysis
    \end{center}

    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=1\textheight]{some_image.jpg}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

(Note: I removed most of the unnecessary code in the example code, so the theme in the picture doesn't match with the default one in the example code anymore. --Caramdir)

Comment: Bonus kharma of course

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can include the picture into a TikZ node and then draw some rectangles over it. For example,

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{ESR1} 

    \begin{center}
        Functional analysis
    \end{center}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=1\textheight]{some_image.jpg}};
            \draw<1>[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (1.6,1) rectangle (\textheight-1cm,5);
            \draw<2>[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (5.7,4.1) rectangle (7.5,4.9);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

with [a picture from Wikipedia](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/Mycena_interrupta.jpg) as `some_image.jpg` gives the two slides

[image: example]

Note the `\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\includegraphics{...}};` line. This adds the picture so that the lower left corner is at the origin of the TikZ coordinate system. Section 14.6 “Rounding Corners” of the TikZ manual (v2.10) tells you how you can change the corner rounding.

Btw, do you really mean `width=1\textheight`?

Comment: Accepted fastest solution.  Testing now.

Comment: I think the text's height is the limiting factor for this image when the title is taken into account.  I may be wrong, maybe that command doesn't even consider the title.

Comment: `width=1\textheight` sets the *width* of the picture to the *height* of the text.

Comment: @denilw, you should test before accepting...

Comment: There is an updated version of this answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9561/15107 that is worth looking at.

Answer (score 23):

Damn you Caramdir, four minutes too late!

Anyway, here's what I came up with. Caramdir's is at least as good, but mine is a bit closer to your syntax, maybe...

```
\documentclass[english,ignorenonframetext,table]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% A simple dot to overcome graphicx limitations
\newcommand{\lyxdot}{.}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
 % this default might be overridden by plain title style
 \newcommand\makebeamertitle{\frame{\maketitle}}%
 \AtBeginDocument{
   \let\origtableofcontents=\tableofcontents
   \def\tableofcontents{\@ifnextchar[{\origtableofcontents}{\gobbletableofcontents}}
   \def\gobbletableofcontents#1{\origtableofcontents}
 }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usetheme{Frankfurt} %Warsaw
\usecolortheme{albatross}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\newcommand{\tformating}{
 \definecolor{darkPurple}{rgb}{0.101960784313725,0,0.2}
 \definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.2,0,0.4}
 \definecolor{lightPurple}{rgb}{0.4,0,0.4}
 \rowcolors[]{1}{darkPurple}{purple}
 \small
}

\usepackage{tikz,overpic}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.misc}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\frametitle{ESR1} 

\begin{center}
Functional analysis
\par\end{center}

\begin{center}
\only<1>{\begin{overpic}[width=1\textheight]{some_image.jpg}
\end{overpic}}%
\only<2>{\begin{overpic}[width=1\textheight]{some_image.jpg}
\put(40,38){\tikz \draw[red,thick,rounded corners] (0,0) rectangle (5,1.2);}
\end{overpic}}%
\only<3>{\begin{overpic}[width=1\textheight]{some_image.jpg}
\put(40,38){\tikz \draw[red,thick,rounded corners] (0,0) rectangle (5,1.2);}
\put(0,14){\tikz \draw[red,thick,rounded corners] (0,0) rectangle (3.5,1.2);}
\end{overpic}}%
\par\end{center}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Some of my code came from your earlier code, which was changed. Grr! ;)

Comment: But you have an animated gif!

Comment: Yep. Does that get *me* any bonus points?

Comment: I'm very impressed by the animated gif.  Bonus kharma and +1 for you.

Comment: Solution works.

Answer (score 11):

## NOTES

Because I use PSTricks, the image is in eps format.
My compilation steps are

1. `latex.exe` to convert .tex to .dvi.
2. `dvips.exe` to convert .dvi to .ps.
3. `ps2pdf.exe` to convert .ps to .pdf.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pstricks}


\newdimen\ImageW
\ImageW=8cm

\newdimen\ImageH
\ImageH=6cm

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{ESR1} 

    \begin{center}
        Functional analysis
    \end{center}

    \begin{center}
        \pspicture(\ImageW,\ImageH)
        \rput(0.5\ImageW,0.5\ImageH){\includegraphics[width=\ImageW]{pitfall}}
        %\psgrid%turn on or off for navigational purpose during development
        \pause
        \psset{linecolor=red,linewidth=2pt,framearc=0.5}
        \psframe(5.2,3.8)(6.4,5.6)\pause
        \psframe(2.7,0)(4.5,1)       
        \endpspicture
    \end{center}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```