# Drawing on an image with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams, asymptote

Recently I have learned how to draw simple stuff with TikZ. I really like it. Now I wonder if it is possible to draw with TikZ on a image. Instead of pasting a image in Illustrator and adding some vectors to point something in the picture I would like to do it using TikZ. Is it possible?

For example, on a picture of a computer (PNG,etc) I would like to draw some arrows and labels saying "Keyboard", "Monitor", etc.

Comment: a couple of years later: Ignasi asked me to add a link to the related answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38632/image-with-axis/38634#comment355583_38634

Answer (score 558, accepted):

(The first part of this answer [is taken from my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8911/in-a-beamer-slide-highlight-a-region-of-an-image-with-a-rectangle-overlay/8917#8917) to a similar—but not identical—question.)

You can put an `\includegraphics` inside a TikZ node and then draw over it. The following code adds the picture so that the lower left corner is at the origin of the TikZ coordinate system.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{some_image.jpg}};
    \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (7.5,5.3) rectangle (9.4,6.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With [a picture](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/Mycena_interrupta.jpg) from Wikipedia as `some_image.jpg`, this yields

[image: example]

There is a slight problem with this solution: whenever you choose to scale the image differently (e.g. with `width=0.9\textwidth`), you have to correct the coordinates for your annotations. So it might be useful to introduce coordinates relative to the picture:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{some_image.jpg}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.62,0.65) rectangle (0.78,0.75);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Then inside the `scope`, (0,0) is at the lower left of the picture and (1,1) is at the upper right and scaling the picture automatically scales the annotations (or more correctly, it scales their places; the line width and text size stays the same).

A small warning: If you want to draw circles in the new coordinate system, you have to use a radius with absolute lengths (e.g. `[radius=1cm]`). Otherwise the circle will become an ellipse (if the image is not square).

Comment: I didn't now that `x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}` is possible! Thanks, I used

     `\pgfsetxvec{\pgfpointanchor{image}{south east}}%`
     `\pgfsetyvec{\pgfpointanchor{image}{north west}}%`

so far in my implementation.

Comment: Is there a way to make the scope square? So that only the width goes from 0 to 1?

Comment: @Geoff: I finally got around to implement an option for this. The code is available at [the tex-sx bzr repository](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/files). To use it, download the `onimage.dtx` file and run `pdflatex` on it to obtain the `onimage.sty` and the documentation. (Eventually the package will be available over CTAN.)

Comment: I'm finally trying to compile this, and I get "Undefined control sequence." on lines with `\tse` (l.115). Thanks for any help.

Comment: @Geoff: You mean the code from launchpad? What did you do exactly?

Comment: You could also define two additional commands as stated her: http://kogs-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/~meine/tikz/, then the coordinates of the drawing over the image can be set in image coordinates, something I used extensively in my PhD-thesis...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Say, instead of using `rectangle` as noted, one wants to use to use something like `\node[minimum width=0.2\imagewidth]`; what would be the best way to extract the width `\imagewidth` of node `(image)` in this kind of approach?

Comment: I just generalized the approach presented here, because this one here relies on the `south west anchor being in `(0,0)` for the image; see my extended version (unsing relative coordinates in two images/nodes) http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/214390/8042

Comment: 4 years later, `onimage` is still not on CTAN. Would you please consider uploading it? It is such a useful package!

Comment: how do i write text on the image ?

Comment: @Kong Using TikZ nodes.

Answer (score 508):

This is meant to be an addition to Caramdir's answer, but I cannot figure out how to insert line breaks into comments:

To make it easier to find the desired points in the new coordinate system, you can draw a labeled grid on top of the image while you're working on it:

```
\draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
\foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
```

[image: image with grid]

Complete example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{some_image.jpg}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very useful addition!

Comment: **Superb! Brilliant!**

Comment: By the way you can insert line beaks in the comments by using `Shift+Enter`. But I'm glad this isn't a comment so that I can upvote.

Comment: @leo Note that even though you see the line breaks,

they won't persist once you submit the comment.  Excellent technique, though (if I'm not too late to the party!) :)

Comment: It would be great to have a complete example here with all packages and inclusion of the picture.

Comment: I support the idea of @Masi regarding a complete example.

Comment: I know this is an old post but what if our picture is rectangular ? Then when we use commands such as \draw[] (0.5,0.5) circle (0.1), the circle is not a circle. How can we avoid this and make a square grid for example?

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a complete example; feel free to reverse the edit.

Comment: It seems trivial, but what if I want to number from 1 to 10 instead of 0.1...0.9...?

Comment: Helps me good, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/560471/46023

Comment: how do i write text on the image ?

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very useful!

Answer (score 120):

For PSTricks fans, the solution is also simple. Unlike Caramdir's and Jake's solutions which use decimal numbers for normalization, I use integer instead. I believe that using integer is better. :-)

There are three steps as follows:

1. Specify the number of columns and rows. Higher values ease you to determine positions more accurately. Unless you are happy to redo the third step, avoid changing these values after completing the third step.
2. Specify the scale. Scaling does not affect what you have done in the third step.
3. Superimposing is done here. To enable the grid, change `showgrid` from `false` to `top`. The grid will be useful to determine positions.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\def\M{4}% columns
\def\N{4}% rows
\def\scale{0.25}% scale
\def\filename{mycena_interrupta}% filename


\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics[scale=\scale]{\filename}}

\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}
{
    gridcolor=yellow,
    subgridcolor=gray,
    subgriddiv=10,
    griddots=0,
    subgriddots=5,
    gridwidth=0.4pt,
    subgridwidth=0.2pt,
}

\psset
{
   xunit=0.5\dimexpr\wd\IBox/\M,
   yunit=0.5\dimexpr\ht\IBox/\N,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](-\M,-\N)(\M,\N)
    \rput(0,0){\usebox\IBox}
    \psframe[linecolor=red,linewidth=2pt,dimen=inner,framearc=0.5](0.9,1.2)(2.2,2)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

When `showgrid=top`:

[image]

The final result with `showgrid=false`:

[image]

Comment: How Can you change your origo to be at the bottom left corner?

Answer (score 60):

[image]

MWE using `Asymptote` `graphic()` label:

```
% igrid.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{asy}
import graph;
import math;

defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));
real sc=2;
unitsize(sc*1bp);
real wd=200*sc;
real ht=120*sc;

// Image used from http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/Mycena_interrupta.jpg
label(
  shift(wd/2,ht/2)*
  graphic("img.jpg"
  ,"width="+string(wd)+"bp"
  +",height="+string(ht)+"bp"
  +",scale="+string(sc)
  ),(0,0)
);
layer();

draw(((0,0)--(wd,ht)/sc),blue+2pt);

int ngrid=10;
int n=(int)(wd/ngrid/sc);
int m=(int)(ht/ngrid/sc);
add(scale(ngrid)*grid(n,m,yellow));

//xlimits(0,wd/sc,crop=true);
//ylimits(0,ht/sc,crop=true);
xaxis( 0,wd/sc,RightTicks(Step=ngrid));
yaxis(0,ht/sc,LeftTicks(Step=ngrid));

pair[] P={
(66,34),
(70,35),
(76,38),
(80,37),
(84,37),
(87,42),
(90,49),
(91,54),
(92,60),
(93,65),
(97,65),
(100,65),
(103,66),
(105,67),
(101,71),
(97,74),
(95,75),
(92,76),
(94,78),
(98,79),
(101,80),
(103,80),
(103,83),
(100,85),
(96,88),
(91,87),
(86,86),
(82,86),
(78,86),
(74,86),
(70,83),
(69,83),
(67,86),
(65,87),
(59,88),
(54,88),
(51,87),
(47,87),
(42,86),
(38,85),
(34,84),
(31,82),
(29,80),
(29,77),
(33,76),
(35,76),
(36,76),
(36,74),
(35,73),
(33,70),
(33,69),
(36,68),
(40,68),
(41,68),
(44,67),
(46,67),
(47,64),
(47,60),
(49,55),
(52,48),
(55,41),
(58,35),
(63,31),
};
guide g=graph(P,operator..)..cycle;
fill(g,white+opacity(0.8));
draw(g,orange+1bp);
\end{asy}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

% To process it with `latexmk`, create file `latexmkrc`:
% 
%     sub asy {return system("asy '$_[0]'");}
%     add_cus_dep("asy","eps",0,"asy");
%     add_cus_dep("asy","pdf",0,"asy");
%     add_cus_dep("asy","tex",0,"asy");
% 
% and run `latexmk -pdf igrid.tex`.
```

Answer (score 54):

To easily **get the precise relative positions** (which is often quite tedious) and to generate LaTeX code automatically for such example as shown below, you could use the new web-based [**LaTeX Overlay Generator**](http://ff.cx/latex-overlay-generator/), which I built for such cases. This is just a small interactive tool, which helps you to find the right locations without using a manual grid-based approach.

[image: Example]

## LaTeX Code

In the following the source code of a minimal working example generated by the [**LaTeX Overlay Generator**](http://ff.cx/latex-overlay-generator/).

```
\documentclass{article}

% remove "[demo]" if you want include actual image!!!
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% LaTeX Overlay Generator - Annotated Figures v0.0.1
% Created with http://ff.cx/latex-overlay-generator/
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\annotatedFigureBoxCustom{bottom-left}{top-right}{label}{label-position}{box-color}{label-color}{border-color}{text-color}
\newcommand*\annotatedFigureBoxCustom[8]{\draw[#5,thick,rounded corners] (#1) rectangle (#2);\node at (#4) [fill=#6,thick,shape=circle,draw=#7,inner sep=2pt,font=\sffamily,text=#8] {\textbf{#3}};}
%\annotatedFigureBox{bottom-left}{top-right}{label}{label-position}
\newcommand*\annotatedFigureBox[4]{\annotatedFigureBoxCustom{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{white}{white}{black}{black}}
\newcommand*\annotatedFigureText[4]{\node[draw=none, anchor=south west, text=#2, inner sep=0, text width=#3\linewidth,font=\sffamily] at (#1){#4};}
\newenvironment {annotatedFigure}[1]{\centering\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) { #1};\begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]}{\end{scope}\end{tikzpicture}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[h!t]

        \begin{annotatedFigure}
            {\includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{black-demo.png}}
            \annotatedFigureBox{0.084,0.614}{0.394,0.804}{A}{0.084,0.614}%bl
            \annotatedFigureBox{0.222,0.284}{0.3743,0.4934}{B}{0.3743,0.4934}%tr
            \annotatedFigureBox{0.555,0.784}{0.6815,0.874}{C}{0.555,0.784}%bl
            \annotatedFigureBox{0.557,0.322}{0.8985,0.5269}{D}{0.8985,0.5269}%tr
        \end{annotatedFigure}

        \caption{\textbf{Lorum Ipsum Overview} -- Lorem ipsum dolor amet (A), consetetur (B) elitr, sed diam (C) nonumy eirmod invidunt ut labore (D).}
        \label{fig:teaser}

    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 54):

In meantime there is a new package [callouts](http://ctan.org/pkg/callouts)

In the annotate-environment you define the image width and an annotation scale. If you scale both with the same factor, then you can change the size of the image without loosing the correct relative positions.

Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl} % use larger type; default would be 10pt
\usepackage[wby]{callouts}

\begin{document}
  % pic-source: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/Mycena_interrupta.jpg
  \begin{annotate}{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Mycena_interrupta}}{1}
    % \helpgrid
    \note{0,0}{Center}
    \callout{4,3}{Mushrom}{3,2}
    \arrow{-3,-2.4}{-4.5,-3}
    %And raw tikz
    \draw[very thick,red] (-4,4) rectangle (-3,3);
  \end{annotate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great package! Simple and to the point.

Comment: I'm wondering why this answer has attracted way less attention as it should, cause this solution is just super straightforward :)

Answer (score 21):

For simple tasks, such a heavy weapon like `tikz` is not always necessary. If only simple shapes or text should be added a `picture` environment is more then enough:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
bla

\begin{picture}(1,0.55038404)%
  \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{17D2J}}%
  \put(150,50){x axis}%
\end{picture}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Example based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/347168/36296)

An overview of available shapes inside the `picture` environment can be found at http://www.weinelt.de/latex/picture.html (unfortunately I only found it in German, does anyone know an English version? Or another overview?)

Answer (score 17):

Since 2019, we have the [tikz-imagelabels](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-imagelabels) package. I think it has been bundled in TeX Live 2019 onwards.

This package does what the question asks entirely using the standard tikz macros.

Example (taken from the documentation) below. Image [source](https://hubblesite.org/contents/news-releases/2004/news-2004-20.html).

```latex
    \documentclass{standalone}
     \usepackage{tikz-imagelabels}

     \begin{document}
     \begin{annotationimage}{width=6cm}{pleiades.jpg}
       \draw[annotation left = {Atlas at 0.3}] to (0.11,0.4);
       \draw[annotation left = {Pleione at 0.55}] to (0.11,0.49);
       \draw[annotation left = {Alcyone at 0.8}] to (0.39,0.45);
       \draw[annotation below = {Merope at 0.5}] to (0.58,0.28);
       \draw[annotation right = {Electra at 0.3}] to (0.84,0.45);
       \draw[annotation right = {Caleano at 0.75}] to (0.85,0.64);
       \draw[annotation above = {Maia at 0.4}] to (0.67,0.72);
       \draw[annotation above = {Taygeta at 0.9}] to (0.78,0.82);
       \draw[image label = {M45 at south east}];
     \end{annotationimage}
     \end{document}
```

[image: Output of tikz-imagelabels example]

Comment: Please extend your answer with an example of use of this package

Comment: @Zarko, There you go - example added.