# How to connect figures by arrows in Beamer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

In a related post; [How to connect Beamer blocks by arrows?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96289/how-to-connect-beamer-blocks-by-arrows), I found this image (latex+beamer):
[image]

I would like to do the exact same thing, but replace the 3 blocks by 3 figures. The figures may have different sizes. Any suggestions how I could do that?

Comment: Would TikZ help? I'm not sure what you mean by "figures" but if they're diagrams, TikZ is good at that anyway; if they're images, you can include them through TikZ and if it's text/tables, you can make a TikZ figure with three nodes each containing a minipage.

Comment: You might be able to adapt [this example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/beamer-arrows/) based on TikZ (from [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net/))

Comment: I think you might also find useful [Anchors badly positioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97089/13304) (second part of the answer).

Answer (score 1):

No `tikz` involved here.  However, you might be able to find better arrow graphics than those I pulled by scaling up stuff from he `MnSymbol` package.  Where I put my `\rule`s, you can substitute an `\includegraphics`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\centering
\def\figA{\rule{1in}{1in}}
\def\figB{\rule{1.3in}{1in}}
\def\figC{\rule{1.2in}{0.8in}}
\def\arrowA{\scalebox{6}{$\lcurvearrowright$}}
\def\arrowB{\scalebox{6}{$\lcurvearrowsw$}}
\def\arrowC{\scalebox{6}{$\lcurvearrownw$}}
\begin{document}
\stackon[-.05in]{\hspace{.3in}\figA\hspace{.5in}\figB}{\arrowA}\\
\hspace{.2in}\arrowC\belowbaseline[-.3in]{\figC}\arrowB
\end{document}
```

[image]