# I am trying to post a picture adjacent to bullet points

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

Please check the code block below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
{
\frametitle{Characteristics of ABCDE}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.5\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item AAAAAAA   
\item BBBBBBBBBB
\item CCCCCCCCCC
\item DDDDDDDDDDDD
\item EEEEEEEEE
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage} \hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{.4\linewidth}
 \raggedleft
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}
     \draw<1>[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (5.7,4.1) rectangle (7.5,4.9);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{10mm}
\begin{block}{Salient Points}
{
   XyZ xyZ
}
\end{block}
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And the error/problem is ...?

Comment: I cannot get the picture to be adjacent to the text matter. It is actually part of the presentation.

Comment: Is it intentional that you've placed the entire slide content as part of the frame title?

Comment: My apologies, I messed up in trying to "cook" up a generic slide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've edited and changed your code a little bit. Mainly, a `\node` was missing around the `\includepicture`. Is the following what you want to have?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Characteristics of ABCDE}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item AAAAAAA
  \item BBBBBBBBBB
  \item CCCCCCCCCC
  \item DDDDDDDDDDDD
  \item EEEEEEEEE
  \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0cm]
  \node (A) {\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}};
  \draw<1>[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (A.south west) rectangle (A.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace{10mm}
\begin{block}{Salient Points}
{
Reduction in the number of nanotubes per memory cell.
}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Digressing here. I do not want the box to span the entire picture, but only part of the picture? How do I change the \draw line as shown in this [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8911/in-a-beamer-slide-highlight-a-region-of-an-image-with-a-rectangle-overlay/8917#8917)

Comment: @envy_intelligence I think, Harish Kumar has answered this meanwhile.

Answer (score 4):

May be you should use native beamer `columns` instead of `minipage`s. This is just for illustration:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Characteristics of ABCDE}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item AAAAAAA
\item BBBBBBBBBB
\item CCCCCCCCCC
\item DDDDDDDDDDDD
\item EEEEEEEEE
\end{itemize}
\hfill
\column{0.5\linewidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0)
               {\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
    \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
        %helper grid for locating coordinates, comment these 3 lines in the final vesion
        %\draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
        %\foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north,font=\tiny] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
        %\foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east,font=\tiny] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
        \draw[red,ultra thick,rounded corners] (0.35,0.25) rectangle (0.65,0.75);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{columns}

\vspace{10mm}
\begin{block}{Salient Points}
   XyZ xyZ
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]